# Use a unix timestamp for UpdatedAt field in gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm writing an application that communicates with `sqlite3` database using GORM ORM. Now the thing is I need to make `UpdatedAt` column a unix timestamp because another legacy application is using the same database and they should be compatible.

So I tried to update the `UpdatedAt` field with unix timestamp on `BeforeUpdate` hook using the following code block.

```
func (c *CartItems) BeforeUpdate() (err error) {
    fmt.Println("----------------------------------------")
    fmt.Println("BeforeUpdate")
    fmt.Println( c )
    c.UpdatedAt = time.Now().Unix()
    fmt.Println("----------------------------------------")
    return
}
```

but when I run the code query remains same and didn't add the timestamp into the database.

gorm log

```
----------------------------------------
BeforeUpdate
&{55 21 4 7 1585607114 1585607114 {0 [] [] [] {0 0 } 0 0} {0  0 0 0}}
----------------------------------------

[2020-03-31 04:30:02]  [0.46ms]  UPDATE "cart_items" SET "quantity" = 7, "updated_at" = '2020-03-31 04:30:02'  WHERE "cart_items"."id" = 55  
[1 rows affected or returned ] 
[GIN] 2020/03/31 - 04:30:02 | 200 |   97.963597ms |       127.0.0.1 | POST     "/cache/cart/21/item"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following if you want to have `UpdatedAt()` and `CreatedAt()` as unix timestamps.

```golang
type CartItems struct {
    CreatedAt int64
    UpdatedAt int64
}

func (m *CartItems) BeforeUpdate(scope *gorm.Scope) error {
    scope.SetColumn("UpdatedAt", time.Now().Unix())
    return nil
}

func (m *CartItems) BeforeCreate(scope *gorm.Scope) error {
    if m.UpdatedAt == 0 {
        scope.SetColumn("UpdatedAt", time.Now().Unix())
    }

    scope.SetColumn("CreatedAt", time.Now().Unix())
    return nil
}
```

Unfortunately, `gorm` is not well documented so you would have to read the code to understand how this works, namely [this](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/scope.go#L450) line calls the above `BeforeUpdate()` function.

As you can see in the [`callMethod()`](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/scope.go#L432) function, it checks the signature of the function in the `switch` to decide on how to call the function.

Comment: still gorm pass the date time string instead of timestamp in the query ?

Comment: is this still the best way to store timestamp with gorm???